# Issue while trying to save an image to the camera roll SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3, save-image

Encountered a strange issue while trying to save a view.
The picture saved crops out the image.

here is the code :

```
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    let size:CGSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(self.customView!.frame.size.width), height:  CGFloat(self.customView!.frame.size.height))


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( size, false, scale);

    self.customView!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

Please help!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The camera roll has an auto zoom since the height is a bit smaller than the screen.